# Book on bogus proofs or counterexamples in plane geometry

Tags: euclidean-geometry, book-recommendation, plane-geometry

There are books about counterexamples in analysis, topology or probability. Is there any book that focuses on counterexamples in plane geometry or loopholes in geometrical proofs?

I am particularly interested in books that illustrate "honest" false proofs of high-school geometry statements, something like Lewis Carroll's proof that every obtuse angle is equal to a right angle. I vaguely remember that there was a geometry book that discussed, in a small section, how some geometrical proofs contain loopholes because the proof writers forget about the concept of betweenness, but I can't recall the title.

**Edit.** After browsing on amazon.com for hours, I found a book that might be relevant:

A.I. Fetisov and Ya. S. Dubnov, Proof in Geometry: With "Mistakes in Geometric Proofs" ([Dover](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486453545.html)/[amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486453545))

According to an [MAA review](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/proof-in-geometry-with-mistakes-in-geometric-proofs), this is actually a compilation of two separate books, *Proof in Geometry* by Fetisov and *Mistakes in Geometric Proofs* by Dubnov. The review is only neutral, and I have yet to see if the proofs are good (or should I say "bad"?) enough.

Answer (score 1):

*Theorems and Counterexamples in Mathematics* by Gelbaum and Olmsted has a [section on plane Euclidean geometry](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=kUPtBwAAQBAJ&pg=PR30&lpg=PR30&dq="Counterexamples+for+the+parallel+axiom"&source=bl&ots=hpiMsco9cS&sig=ACfU3U0JUBIhUqk5F8aBpLWmivw4viccPg&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjcnLiRr8XgAhVAF7kGHdqDD4MQ6AEwAHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q="Counterexamples%20for%20the%20parallel%20axiom"&f=false)

Comment: Thanks for the information. As the section contains only two examples, I'll see if I can borrow a copy of this book.